# Getting a named breakpoint from the browser width and breakpoint object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, breakpoints

I am importing my breakpoint module CSS into JavaScript and am getting an object like this:

```
const breakpoints = {
  large: "992px",
  medium: "768px",
  small: "500px",
  tiny: "320px",
  xlarge: "1384px"
}
```

From `window.innerWidth` I am able to get an integer value of the current browser window width. I would like to use a function that tells the named breakpoint from the window width. For example, a value of `640` would return `medium`.

The logic is hurting my brain. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort your set of values by the integer values and then filter those for values too small and take the first that is big enough.

```
Object.keys(breakpoints)
      .sort((a,b) => parseInt(breakpoints[a], 10) - parseInt(breakpoints[b], 10))
      .filter((s) => { return parseInt(breakpoints[s], 10) > 640 })[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can take a look at this code

```js
const breakpoints = {
  xlarge: [993, 1284],
  large: [769, 992],
  medium: [501, 768],
  small: [321, 500],
  tiny: [0, 320],
};

function checkBreakpoint(numBreakpoint) {
  for (key in breakpoints) {
    if (numBreakpoint >= breakpoints[key][0] && numBreakpoint <= breakpoints[key][1]) {
      return key
    }
  }
}

console.log(checkBreakpoint(1000))
```

You can consider to specify (min width and max width) on each your breakpoints object's property, it will make you easier to define the breakpoint's name, I hope this will help you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how this could be done. Not dynamic like the other answers, but it doesn't need to be complex considering the small number of properties we're talking about here.

```js
const breakpoints = {
  xlarge: "1384px",
  large:   "992px",
  medium:  "768px",
  small:   "500px",
  tiny:    "320px"
}

function getBreakpoint() {
  return matchMedia(`(min-width: ${breakpoints.xlarge})`).matches ? "xlarge" :
         matchMedia(`(min-width: ${breakpoints.large})`).matches ? "large" :
         matchMedia(`(min-width: ${breakpoints.medium})`).matches ? "medium" :
         matchMedia(`(min-width: ${breakpoints.small})`).matches ? "small" :
         matchMedia(`(min-width: ${breakpoints.tiny})`).matches ? "tiny" : "not found"
}

console.log(getBreakpoint())
```